# Unity FindObjectsOfType doesn't find what it should

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, find

My aim is to find all the objects of the given type, do some filter on them using *Linq* and swap their sprites (the swapping works). Note that I'm using this as an editor script, not runtime.

```
var objs = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>()
   .Where(g =>
   {
       var sr = g.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
       if (sr != null)
       {
           if (sr.sprite.name.Equals(_from.name)) { return true; } //error here
           return false;
       }
       return false;
   }).AsEnumerable();
```

It Works *most* of the time, but now I'm getting

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   SwapSprites.m__0 (UnityEngine.GameObject g) (at Assets/SwapSprites.cs:44)

even though I do have a bunch of objects in the scene whose sprite is the one I use as **_from**.

I have no idea what went wrong. I am looking to find all the objects with a *SpriteRenderer* on them whose sprite is the one I'm looking for.

What is strange though that when debugging I do get a bunch of results but ultimately not what I was after and I get this exception eventually.

Comment: Check if your `_from` variable is null

Comment: Any reason to be using `a.Equals(b)` instead of `a==b`? This isn't Java :P

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. `_from` isn't null, I tried debugging it and it was always fine. By the way I give it value by using an object picker so it shouldn't even be null.

Comment: By the way I just saw I got a downvote. If the voter sees this, could s/he tell me what the issue was about? I might correct the question.

Comment: How about  `sr.sprite`? That can be the problem since `_from` is **not** null. Check if `sr.sprite` is null before accessing `name`. ...`if(sr.sprite != null){...}`

Comment: Heh yes, that was the problem. I thought I took care of that in the script before using it but I was sloppy. You might want to convert this to an aswer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already checking  `sr = g.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>()` if is `null` before using it.

The problem can either be `_from.name` or `sr.sprite.name` since both of these are accessing variables from a class which could be `null`.

Note that a `SpriteRenderer` can have its `Sprite` not assigned. In that case, you must also check if the `Sprite` is null before using it or checking its `name` property.

```
 var objs = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Transform>()
 .Where(g =>
 {
     var sr = g.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
     if (sr != null)
     {
         if (sr.sprite != null)
         {
             if (sr.sprite.name.Equals(_from.name)) { return true; } 
         }
         return false;
     }
     return false;
 }).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: And this is how it's done. Can't believe I messed that up :D